# What is the correct way of using an auto_ptr on dynamically allocated arrays?

Tags: c++, auto-ptr

If i use auto_ptr to hold a pointer to a dynamically allocated array, when the auto_ptr gets killed it will use a plain **delete** operation and not **delete[]** thus not deleting my allocated array.

How can i (properly) use auto_ptr on dynamically allocated arrays?

If this is not possible, is there another smart pointer alternative for dynamically allocated arrays?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[boost::shared_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm) is what your looking for.

EDIT:

If you want to avoid the use of boost I would recommend just using `std::vector` they are array's underneath and there is no need to worry about memory allocation. Actually this is a better solution than `shared_array` anyway.

Since you indicate that you wanted to use `auto_ptr` then you don't need the reference counting and ownership model of `shared_array`. So just use a [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) as they are tailored to replace dynamically allocated arrays which is really what you are trying to manage with the use of `auto_ptr`.

Answer (score 10):

You don't. `std::auto_ptr` isn't meant to be used with arrays.

Avoid using `new[]` and `delete[]`.  Use `std::vector` instead.  [This is Stroustrup's recommendation too.](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#auto_ptr)

If you're using an array because you need to pass it to code that expects a pointer, you can simply pass the address of a (non-empty) vector's first element instead.  For example:

```
std::vector<char> buf(size);
fgets(&buf[0], buf.size(), stdin);
```

Note that in C++11, you can (and should) use `buf.data()` instead of `&buf[0]`; `buf.data()` works on an empty vector too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it yourself (i.e. not use boost) then wrap the dynamic array in a class first. Have the class's destructor call `delete[]`. Then the `auto_ptr<Wrapper>` can call `delete` on the class and the memory will be deallocated properly.

Answer (score 1):

The proper boost smart pointer in this case is [boost::scoped_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_array.htm), not the more famous boost::shared_array, because `std::auto_ptr` is a sole ownership pointer. The **opposite** of a shared ownership pointer. In C++0x, the correct pointer is `std::unique_ptr`, which will call delete[] if it is pointing at an array, or delete if it's pointing at a single object.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of using auto_ptr (with a dynamically allocated array or anything else) is to use something else instead. Either boost::shared_array or perhaps shared_ptr> or shared_ptr> from TR1 in your case. In the general case shared_ptr or unique_ptr are smart pointers that are actually smart. Stop using auto_ptr.

Comment: That's just not true. auto_ptr has valid use cases. Admittedly that are not easy for the novice to understand but a blanket you should not use them is just plain bad advice.

Comment: if you have shared_ptr and unique_ptr you are done with figuring whether auto_ptr is going to be safe in this container etc. A tool you need to think carefully about using is a tool I happily abandon when I get a better option; and shared_ptr and unique_ptr are better options.